# Linux, Inter-Process Communication

Tags: linux, runtime, ipc, shared-memory, systems-programming

Which linux shared memory solution supports resizing the shared memory pool at run time?

Comment: rephrase question to make it more understanable

Comment: please add more details - what exactly you need, and what have you tried \ considered